# npm install: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir

Tags: node.js, mobile, npm, appium

I attempted to do a `sudo npm install -g appium` on Mac OS 10.12.5.

I get this error:

```
info Chromedriver Install Installing Chromedriver version '2.30' for platform 'mac' and architecture '64'

info Chromedriver Install Opening temp file to write chromedriver_mac64 to...

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir 

'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-chromedriver/2017820-44752-12jfqpb.z2hd'

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! appium-chromedriver@3.0.1 install: `node install-npm.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
```

This is not a dupe question, as this install attempt was with sudo, as the other one was not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

Comment: I had the same error even with `sudo`, turned out that my network connection has been disconnected. Reconnecting fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Node/NPM. Problem solved.

Answer (score 58):

```
sudo npm install -g appium --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 13):

you are using npm so you have to use

**sudo npm install  --unsafe-perm**
In unsafe mode with every command you run 
 hopefully, it will help

Answer (score 7):

The `-g` option means *install globally*. When packages are *installed globally*, `EACCES` permission errors can occur.

Consider setting up npm to operate globally without elevated permissions. See [Resolving Permission Errors](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally) for more information.

***Option 1***

The best way to avoid permission issues is to reinstall NodeJS and npm using a node version manager.

*1. Install nvm*

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

You can close and reopen the terminal ou just open another terminal and check if nvm is installed properly with this command: `command -v nvm`.

*2. To download and install the latest LTS release of NodeJS, run:*

```
nvm install --lts
```

*3. Set the newly installed NodeJS as the default environment:*

```
nvm alias default lts/*
```

***Option 2*** (Does not apply for windows)

Change the owner of npm's directories to the current user:

```
sudo chown -R $(your_user) /usr/local/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
sudo chown -R $(your_user) ~/.npm ~/.npmrc
```