# Problem with installing puppeteer and handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, puppeteer, handlebars.js

While trying to install puppeteer and handlebars (`npm i`) an error occurs:

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /Users/user/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/61/51
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/user/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/61/51'
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/user/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/61/51
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
```

I've tried to reinstall node-modules but it didn't work :(

I'm working on MacOS.

Comment: Does [npm install: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328267/npm-install-error-eacces-permission-denied-mkdir) help?

Comment: Worked for both, thanks